# Blocking access to request

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework

API receives data by the link {domain}/api2/projects/271/pieces and display them on page, It's work correctly. But when I'm trying access this link simply in browser or by command prompt (curl ...) I have message {"message":"FORBIDDEN"}

I checked .htacces [image: .htacces]

Seems like it's ok.

Application use Zend 1 framework. Page use WordPress
What could be the reason?

Comment: That htaccess doesn't have anything to do with the error. Is the link you're trying to access (which returns the forbidden) your app? You probably have some rule in the application that requires some authentication, some specific user agent, a xmlhttp-header or something. It's impossible for us to know without seeing the actual code/route for that endpoint

Comment: where this rules is set in zend 1 framework?

Comment: I don't know zend 1, so you need to start with the route, then the controller and so on to see if you see any restrictions somewhere.

Comment: it can be Authentication. or the request method. ?

Comment: It's request method